# Opening and Reading a .txt file from the python script

Tags: python

```
from sys import argv
script,filename=argv
txt=open(filename)
print("here's your file %r:\n" % filename)
print txt.read()

print("type the filename again:")
file_again=input("@")
txt_again=open(file_again)
print txt_again.read()
```

I have used this code and it's showing error like in the image attached.

What should I do?

[image]

Comment: argv might be a list in your case.Please put the error you are facing

Comment: where is the image?

Comment: `python.exe` requires a script (*.py file*), not a text file you want to read.

Comment: @bigbounty i didn't put .py script in cmd which popped the error. I got the answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to execute a `.txt` file. You should run your script like this:

```
C:\path\to\python.exe my_script.py path\to\your\file.txt
```

Where `my_script.py` should contain your code.